# In terminal-ide how do I get telnetd to start automatically whenever the device turns on?

Tags: terminal, auto-start

I think terminal-ide is the best thing since sliced bread but I am not sure how to get the telnetd to start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a better solution for now, but I could do it by adding `telnetd` in the end of the `.bashrc` file. It is run many times, but the command fails if the address is already in use anyway.

This is a quick hack, but it would be nice to have an initialization script run when the app starts.